# Google Cloud Spark ElasticSearch TransportClient connection exception

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using Spark on Google Cloud and I have the following code to connect to an Elasticsearch database

```
 import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
 import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
 import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
 import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
 import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
 import org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit;


 public  TransportClient openConnection(String ipAddress, int ipPort) throws UnknownHostException {

    Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
    TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().
            addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress), ipPort));

    return client;

}
```

When I run it locally, i.e. `spark-submit --master local[*]` everything runs OK. When I run it in a google cloud spark cluster I get the following Exception:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient$Builder.build(TransportClient.java:131)
at javaTools.ElasticSearchConnection.openConnection(ElasticSearchConnection.java:24)
```

The last referred method (`openConnection`) is the connection described above.

The code is uploaded to the google cloud using a fat jar created using sbt asssembly, so all libraries used are common, except for the native java ones.

I am thinking it might be some library dependency, since the same jar runs fine on my local computer and it is able to connect to the ElasticSearch  server, but the same  jar fails to run on the spark cluster on Google cloud. Both local and and cloud versions of `Spark` are the same, 1.6.0.

Comment: If you run `jar tf your-jarfile.jar | grep ThreadPool` do you see the classfile `org/elasticsearch/threadpool/ThreadPool.class`? Often a local dev environment can get polluted with dependencies that hide missing fatjar dependencies; have you tried a completely clean environment where you download a completely fresh [Spark tarball](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) in a clean environment (say, a new local or cloud VM) and run the same `spark-submit --master local` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused due to conflicting Guava libraries used in Spark and Elasticsearch. The solution can be found [in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987541/spark-on-yarn-confilict-with-elasticsearch-transportclient-because-of-guava-libr)